# Blank space in div with scrolling

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to scroll an image and I had the following:

```
<div id="content">
    <img id="undertaking-image">
</div>

#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

But the result shows an empty space before the bottom scroll bar.

[Screenshot showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebblC.png)

Answer (score -2):

Are you applying any styles to the `img`?

Try:

```
img {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  block: 0;
}
```

Without knowing more about the CSS that should cover the bases.